# SDE and expectation of stopping time

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $X_t$ be a solution to the SDE, $dX_t=X_t \,dt+X_t\,dW_t $,  $X_0=x>0$ where $W_t$ is brownian motion,
then the solution to this SDE is $X_t=xe^{\frac{t}{2}+W_t}$.

Let $\tau=\inf_{t>0} \{t:X_t\ge R\}$. I am not sure how to calculate the expectation of the stopping time $\mathbb{E}_x[\tau]$.

Thank you

Comment: Do you know what the expected value of the hitting time of a given level $a$ is for standard Brownian motion (with or without drift)?

Comment: Can you solve similar hitting times problems? Which ones?

Comment: I am not very comfortable with hitting time actually :(

Comment: I know how to do the basic ones, like first passage time

Comment: @cardinal, I know how to calculate the problem you mentioned

Comment: This *is* a first-passage time problem.

Comment: Both with and without drift (the latter is especially trivial, the former is more relevant to this problem)?

Comment: so we  calculate $P(\tau\le t)$?

Comment: Here is a **hint** that may help: Consider $Y_t = \log X_t$. What kind of process is this? Can you redefine $\tau$ in terms of $Y_t$? Now, proceed...

Comment: so we  calculate $P(\tau\le t)$= $2P\{X_t>R \}$??  

$Y_t$ is just normal

Comment: how do you redefine $\tau$?

Comment: @TashaChen: if $X_t \geq R$ then $Y_t = \log X_t\geq ...$ (or maybe $Y_t\leq \dots$)

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $(W_t)_{t\geqslant0}$ is a martingale, hence the optional stopping theorem yields $\mathbb{E}[W_\tau]=\mathbb{E}[W_0]$. 
Thus, $\mathbb{E}[W_\tau]=\mathbb{E}_x[\log(X_\tau)-\log(X_0)-\frac{1}{2}\tau]=0$
and $\mathbb{E}_x[\tau]=2\log(R/x)$.

Answer (score 0):

The optional stopping theorem states that if $(W_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is a ***uniformly integrable*** martingale, and $\tau$ is a stopping time, then $\mathbb{E}[W_{\tau}]=\mathbb{E}[W_0]$.

Hence whilst Grim Reapers answer above is true, it is not rigorous, and requires some details to be filled in.

Consider the stopped process $(W_{t\land n})_{t\geq 0}$, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. This is now a uniformly integrable martingale (it is a stopped process with respect to a bounded stopping time), and thus we can apply to optional stopping theorem to it.

So $0=\mathbb{E}[W_0]=\mathbb{E}[W_{n\land\tau}]=\mathbb{E}[log(X_{n\land\tau})-log(x)-\frac{1}{2}(n\land\tau)]^{(*)}$

Since $log(X_{n\land\tau})$ is bounded above by R, by the dominated convergence theorem, $\mathbb{E}[log(X_{n\land\tau})]\to log(R)$ as $n\to\infty$. And since $(n\land\tau)$ is monotonic increasing, by the monotonic convergence theorem, $\mathbb{E}[n\land\tau]\to\mathbb{E}[\tau]$ as $n\to\infty$. And hence rearranging $^{(*)}$ and taking $n\to\infty$ gives $\mathbb{E}[\tau]=2\mathbb{E}[log(R/x)]$